# I am getting run-time error 6 with export to excel code, with button click

Tags: ms-access

I am getting `run-time error 6` with this code:

I am trying to open report and then export to Excel with a click of button in a form.

Form lists multiple reports, user selects from a list of reports, and then clicks the button `Generate Report` to preview report and export to excel.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.lstReports) Then

    DoCmd.OpenReport Me.lstReports, IIf((Me.frmGenerateRpt = "1"), acViewPreview, acViewNormal), , strWhere

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "CRMDetailCommissionsStatements", acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\csusaava\Documents\July 2018 Comissions\Access_Trial\New Database\CRMDetailCommissionsStatements.xls"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "NBCommissionReport", acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\csusaava\Documents\July 2018 Comissions\Access_Trial\New Database\NBCommissionsStatements.xls"

End If
```

Comment: Which line produces the error? In first `DoCmd` the user selects a report, as you described, but in second and third there are hardcoded reportname And what about `strWhere`?

Comment: the error is produced in second and third line, when it is trying to export to excel. and the export fails. First line of code is working fine.

Comment: The OutputTo syntax works for me. What report is opened by OpenReport? Why would opening a report be necessary for the export of 2 other reports? What is full error message?

Comment: Export is so that historic data can be stored, but user needs to see the report open. The report selected from the 'list of reports' will be opened. Multiple reports are available to select from the Form. Full Error is:  Runtime Error 6: Data Overflow. Do you think I need to clean up some memory on my computer or something?